# Asymptotic behaviour of x(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Given the equation:  $ x^2 + \ln^2x = n $.

Let $x(n)$ - root of the equation and $x(n) > 1$

The problem: find missing terms in following sum:
$$ x(n) \approx ... + O(\frac{\ln^4n}{n})$$

I've found the first term and get next result:

$$ x(n) \approx \sqrt{n} + ... + O(\frac{\ln^4n}{n}) $$

How to determine remaining terms of the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let $x=\sqrt{n}-y$, where $y=o(\sqrt n)$. Now:
$$(\sqrt{n}-y)^2+\ln^2(\sqrt{n}-y)=n$$
$$-2\sqrt{n}\cdot y + y^2 + \ln^2\sqrt n + \left(\ln(1-\frac{y}{\sqrt n})\right)^2=0$$
Now discard the smaller terms and see what remains:
$$-2\sqrt{n}\cdot y + \ln^2\sqrt n = 0$$
$$y = \left.\left({1\over2}\ln n\right)^2\right/2\sqrt{n}$$
(plus some small-o, of course).

Comment: Can you explain why $y^2=o(n)$ has been discarded? It does not look too small.

Comment: If $y=o(\sqrt n)$, then $y^2=o(y\cdot\sqrt n)$.

Comment: Yes, but $y=o(\sqrt{n})$ could make $y^2$ much larger than $\ln^2\sqrt{n}$. Thus one cannot discard the former and keep the larger as the answer is presently doing. More work is needed.

Comment: In addition, note that this answer, problematic to say the least, was accepted **12 minutes** after it was posted, making quite unlikely that the OP took the time to digest it and check it thoroughly.

Comment: If $y^2$ were as large as $\ln^2n$ or larger, then $y\sqrt n$ would be even larger, and wouldn't have anything to cancel out with. I agree, of course, that my answer is but a sketch rather than a proof.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You cannot neglect quadratic terms **even if they are small** first and then solve the rest. You have to solve first and then approximate. For example, take $\epsilon y^2-2y+2=0$. Your method gives $-2y+2=0$, i.e. $y=1$, but another solution explodes to $\infty$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: In your example we don't have the reason to believe that the quadratic term is small; $\epsilon$ may be small, but we don't know what $y$ is. In this problem, we do know that $y=o(\sqrt n)$; that was our assumption from the very beginning. Anyway, if you insist, let's just discard the second logarithm term (which is $o(1)$ anyway), solve the quadratic equation for $y$, approximate the solution and get exactly the same result.

Comment: @IvanNeretin In this problem, *small* means $O(\frac{\ln^4n}{n})$ for $x$, which means $o(\sqrt{n})$ is huge, even $o(1)$ can be much larger than accepted. Your solution is very fishy.

Comment: $o(\sqrt n)$ is $o(\sqrt n)$; we don't need to know if it is huge with respect to 1 or anything else. Again, I agree that my answer is far from rigorous. Normally the OP should have been asking the very questions you are asking.